# Simple ASP.NET MVC 2 Question - Using the Edit Scaffold

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Good Morning,

I am using the editing scaffold. Here is the two bits of code: 
Controller Code:

```
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var viewModel = new ListingManagerViewModel
            {
                Listing = AfvClassifiedsDB.Listings.Single(l => l.ListingID == id),
                Categories = AfvClassifiedsDB.Categories.ToList(),
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        //
        // POST: /ListingManager/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            var listing = AfvClassifiedsDB.Listings.Single(l => l.ListingID == id);
            try
            {
                // Save the changes to Listing.

                UpdateModel(listing, "Listings");
                AfvClassifiedsDB.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                // An error has occured so redisplay the form instead.

                var viewModel = new ListingManagerViewModel
                {
                    Listing = listing,
                    Categories = AfvClassifiedsDB.Categories.ToList(),
                };

                return View(viewModel);
            }
        }
```

View Code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AfvClassifieds.ViewModels.ListingManagerViewModel>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Edit
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Edit</h2>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>

            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Listing, new { Categories = Model.Categories })%>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

This seems to work, but when you submit the form, the values aren't changed. This has been created using the MVC Music Store as a guide. No errors, but the form values I create aren't submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the `UpdateModel` method?
However, it is clearly that you don't update anything there. You didn't do anything to the form collection `FormCollection collection`. the `FormCollection` is the actual form data that is inserted by user, so you should take all the values from it and save it in db.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have based this solution off of this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-5. I have looked back and it looks spot on, I thought the UpdateModel() Method was built into MVC?

Comment: are you using ViewModel? check this link http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/17/asp-net-mvc-using-controller-updatemodel-when-using-a-viewmodel/